# acces html form fields inside django view with request objects

Tags: django, forms, view, request

so i have a html form the user fills, one of them is name='name', how can a acces them in a view using the request parameter

what about request.POST.name ?

Answer (score 1):

`request.POST` is a dict. So, you can't access the keys of request.POST as you can do with the attributes of an object.

A simple solution to your problem can be:

```
name = request.POST.get('name')
```

So, name will either be the value passed in the form or None.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  `id` property is not passed in the `request`.

You should use the `name="some_name"` attribute of the html input.  And it will be available as `request.POST['some_name']`.